# How to throttle API http request

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

I am currently building an endpoint to process a large amount of data. However I am running into an error over running out of resources. I'm pretty sure the issue is the fact that I am making too many request to the server without limiting it. However every attempt to throttle it has been unsuccessful. So I'm looking at how I can throttle my asynchronous endpoint and avoid this issue.

- SPECIFIC ERROR
  net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES

Code

```
 const sendStepData = async() =>{
    try{

        const body = {a,b,c,d,e,f}

        assignToBody(body)

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/stepdata',{
                method:"POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })}catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }
    
}
```

Even after adding a SetTimeOut I am unable to throttle the endpoint.

Code with timeout

```
 const sendStepData = async() =>{
    try{

        const body = {a,b,c,d,e,f}

        assignToBody(body)

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/stepdata',{
                method:"POST",
                headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })}catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }
    
}

const delayQue = () =>{
    setTimeout(sendStepData,5000)
}
```

One thing to clarify as well that may be helpful. This endpoint is in a separate file that I call after I have prepped my data to be passed to my db.

I'll even take suggestions at material to look at if it may help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can look into streaming, so that you can process the huge data in manageable chunks. This way it won't impact the resources. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve with the setTimeout, but delaying every request with 5 sec just delays the same load with 5 sec, so no wonder it did not solve the problem. Caching, merging requests, checking if you really need all data, is eventual consistence okay with what delay, websockets, sending events instead of states, maybe such things could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debounce your method :

```
let now = Date.now();
const delayQue = () =>{
    if(Date.now() - now > 5000) {
        now = Date.now();
        sendStepData()
    }
}
```

it will only make the call if 5000ms has passed since the last call,
and it will wait 5000ms before the first call also.

You can also wait for the 5000ms to pass and call the method

```
let now = Date.now();
let timeoutId = null;
const delayQue = () =>{
    if(Date.now() - now > 5000) {
        now = Date.now();
        sendStepData()
    } else if(!timeoutId) {
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            now = Date.now();
            sendStepData();
            timeoutId = null,    
        },  5000 - (Date.now() - now))
    }
}
```

you could look for the lodash debounce method also, if you don't want to do it yourself, and have a more complete solution

Comment: I have tried to debounce it before and was unsuccessful however I wouldn't be surprised if it was just me so I'll go ahead and look into it again. However if I debounce they way you showed in your first example then wouldn't I miss out on making request leaving holes in my data?

Comment: Well it depends what you want to do, you can choose to drop those requests, or just add them to a queue

Comment: This is the correct answer I had to do a little restructuring and had to pass all the data instead of in pieces. Another answer was to use a callback function.